# R parallel - clusters inside a cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

## Clusterception

I need to run an expensive algorithm 320 times. I can easily parallelize it over 4 clusters running each 80 iterations. I have access to a machine with 32 cores, so I want to further parallelize the problem. Parallelizing the groups of 80 iterations is trickier, but possible. My idea is to run 8 sub-clusters on each main cluster, each processing 10 iterations.

To test the idea, I have implemented the following dummy code using the parallel package in R. I have tested it on 4 cores and was surprised with the results.

### Normal variables generator

#### Method 1: Parallelize once over 2 clusters

```
library(parallel)
library(tictoc)
N <- 6*10^8 # total number of observations to generate

n.threads <- 2
sample.sizes <- rep(round(N/n.threads, 0), n.threads) # Each cluster generates half of the sample
tic()
cl <- makeCluster(n.threads)
list <- parLapply(cl, sample.sizes, rnorm)
stopCluster(cl)
v <- unlist(list)
toc()
rm(list, v); gc()
```

36 sec exec time; 50% CPU usage

#### Method 2: Parallelize first over 2 clusters, and each cluster is further parallelized over 2 clusters

```
library(parallel)
library(tictoc)

N <- 6*10^8 # total number of observations to generate

rnorm.parallel <- function(N.inside){
  n.threads.inside <- 2
  sample.sizes <- rep(round(N.inside/n.threads.inside, 0), n.threads.inside)  # each sub thread generates 1*10^8 obs
  cl.inside <- makeCluster(n.threads.inside)
  list <- parLapply(cl.inside, sample.sizes, rnorm)
  stopCluster(cl.inside)
  v <- unlist(list)
  return(v)
}

n.threads <- 2
sample.sizes <- rep(round(N/n.threads, 0), n.threads) # each main thread generates 2*10^8 obs
tic()
cl <- makeCluster(length(sample.sizes))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(parallel))
list <- parLapply(cl, sample.sizes, rnorm.parallel)
stopCluster(cl)
v <- unlist(list)
toc()
rm(list, v); gc()
```

42 sec exec time; 100% CPU usage

My conclusion is that although the technique of running clusters inside a cluster  works, the additional overhead makes it less efficient. Is there another package/technique that could help me?

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize at two levels and not just one?

Comment: Because at the top level, I can parallelize without changing the nature of the problem. However at the bottom level, the more I parallelize, the more I need to reframe my problem. If I could fully parallelize at the top level, it would be ideal. Unfortunately I can't.

Comment: Have a look at the future framework - it allows you to easily configure nested, star-shaped workers, e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-3-topologies.html.  Looking at your code examples, it looks like you wanna use two nested layers of `future.apply::future_lapply()` calls with your nested cluster configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik, your future framework is exactly what I needed. Great contribution to R!